# Why does the C++17 standard not allow converting a string to a bool?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, std, language-design

As per [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars), `std::from_chars` can convert a string to an integer. In C++, `bool` is an integral type. So I think the following code is intuitive and expressive:

```
auto const sv = "true"sv;
auto b = bool{};
std::from_chars(sv.data(), sv.data() + sv.size(), b); // compiler error
assert(b);
```

However, libc++ explicitly deleted the overloaded function:

```
from_chars_result from_chars(const char*, const char*, bool, int = 10) = delete;
```

I just wonder:

**Why does the C++17 standard not allow converting a string to a bool?**

Comment: I have no specific insight, but I suspect it's likely because the result of your snippet would be a parse failure, leaving `b == false`, which is unintuitive enough to just not allow it at all.

Comment: The `result.ec` will inidcate a parsing failure.

Comment: For `std::to_chars()`, it has been pointed out that the `bool` overload should be removed in [LWG 3266](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue3266).

Comment: For me the most basic reason is that there is no standard textual representation for bool but there are standard representations for numbers.  Also intuitive is highly subjective (opinion based). For me the most natural conversion would look like this 
 `inline constexpr std::string_view my_true_str{"true"}; bool b = (sv==my_true_str);` (assuming the my_true_true is defined in a header file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [LWG 3266](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue3266) which points out that:

> **[charconv.to.chars] does not present an overload for bool (because it is neither a signed nor unsigned integer type), so an attempt to call to_chars with a bool argument would promote it to int and unambiguously call the int overload of to_chars.**
>
> This was not intended, since it is not obvious that the correct textual representation of a bool is 0/1 (as opposed to, say, "true"/"false").
>
> The user should cast explicitly if he wants the 0/1 behavior. (Correspondingly, there is no bool overload for from_chars in the status quo, and conversions do not apply there because of the reference parameter.)

Answer (score -1):

`bool` is not an *integer-type* as used by `<charconv>` (even though it is an *integer type*, without the hyphen).

From [[charconv.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/charconv.syn):

> When a function is specified with a type placeholder of *integer-type*, the implementation provides overloads for all cv-unqualified signed and unsigned integer types and `char` in lieu of *integer-type*.

And from [[basic.fundamental]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.fundamental):

> There are five *standard signed integer types*: “`signed char`”, “`short int`”, “`int`”, “`long int`”, and “`long long int`”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list. There may also be implementation-defined *extended signed integer types*. The standard and extended signed integer types are collectively called *signed integer types*.

> For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) *standard unsigned integer type*: “`unsigned char`”, “`unsigned short int`”, “`unsigned int`”, “`unsigned long int`”, and “`unsigned long long int`”. Likewise, for each of the extended signed integer types, there exists a corresponding *extended unsigned integer type*. The standard and extended unsigned integer types are collectively called *unsigned integer types*.

So `std::from_chars` is defined for `signed char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned char`, `unsigned short int`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int`, `unsigned long long int`, and `char` (as well as any implementation-defined extended signed and unsigned integer types).  Since `bool` is not among those types, `std::from_chars` isn't defined for it.

---

It's important to note that even if `bool` was among the integer types, it wouldn't do what you want.  `std::from_chars` only accepts digits (possibly with a leading `-` sign).  `"true"` would not parse successfully.

Comment: *"bool is not an integer-type..."* **But it is**. See [`bool` is an integer-type](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#11.sentence-2).

Comment: Later `bool` is lumped in with them as “integral types”, which is also called “integer types”.  But it’s not a “signed or unsigned” integer type (even though that might seem exhaustive).

Comment: `bool` is an _integral type_, but per the definitions above, it is not a _signed integer type_ or an _unsigned integer type_, which is what `std::from_chars` is defined for.  In this case the _integer-type_ placeholder used by `<charconv>` is not equivalent to _integer type_ (without the _-_).